# Проблема с русской раскладкой в терминале PhpStorm

Tags: консоль, phpstorm, клавиатура

Не корректно отображаются русские символы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Смените шрифт для консоли
**настройки - editor - color scheme - console font**
(такой путь для мак версии phpstorm)